# mongoexport --collection too many positional options

Tags: mongoexport

I am getting this error when I run mongoexport query.

too many positional arguments: [—-collection thermal_comfort_collection]

```
mongoexport --db gccdb —-collection thermal_comfort_collection --type=csv --fields Timestamp,Temperature,User,ThermalComfort --query '{settingID: ObjectId("58992333441be20c7f834868")}' --out thermal_comfort_103060.csv
```

I've tried 'thermal_comfort_collection' and "thermal_comfort_collection", however, both gave me the same error. How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My issue stemmed from copying and pasting from a different editor (Evernote in this specific case). It transformed my '--' into a long '—', in fact your copying and pasting of the issue looks very similar.

Try deleting out your dashes before "collection" and replacing with typed in dashes --

Comment: It could be why. I solved it by changing the command parameters. I cannot recall exactly since it's been a while. I did remove some parameters and added some as well.